# How do draw separate subranges of data in JavaFX Linechart?

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I need to draw a chart fragments for only certain separate subranges of my data, leaving empty spaces between them. For example, to draw nodes and lines between them for the data whose `x` value falls in range `1..9`, leave an empty space for values `10..12`, and then draw again the data for points `13..30`. Something like the chart shown in the picture. Is there any possibility to do so with JavaFX Linechart?

[image]

Comment: There is no built in way to add gaps in a `LineChart`. You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979363/6395627 for a hack though. It's not ideal to say the least. You're best option might be to subclass `LineChart` and change how it draws itself. I've not subclassed a chart before, however, so I don't know how much control you have over that.

Comment: @Slaw, thanks. That's what I supposed. I'm considering manual drawing with a convas, I guess it would be even simpler.

Comment: @slaw (and op) wondering why you don't use several series?

Comment: @kleopatra You're right, thanks! It's an easy way that works fine. I'll use it.

Comment: @kleopatra You might run into issues with the legend (if you want to display it) where it says the same line is two or more lines. However, I think you're right in this case. The picture example, for instance, looks like it could be a piecewise function where each line is really its own function. In the question I linked it even mentions using multiple series as an option but it just didn't occur to me here... :/

Comment: @Slaw good point, the legend ... thanks :)