# JavaFX: Is there a way to add a break in a LineChart?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, linechart

Say we consider the LineChart from this link:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/java-javafx/javafx-linechart-1.png

I would like there to be a break between empty segments of the chart (in this case, from 0 to near 500), with the chart's y axis in range between the least and max values of the data series.

Can this be accomplished in a LineChart object? Or even in JavaFX at all?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42424166/6395627) may help (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020127/6395627)).

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, As far as I can see, this applies to breaks in the data points. Specifically, I want breaks where there are no values in terms of Y axis.

Comment: Solved. I looked into NumberAxis in FXML to let me set an upper and lower bounds.